# How to reload a web page on CodePen full page view by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, codepen

```
$("#quoteButton").on("click", function() {
    location.reload();
});
```

I worked on a 'Random Quote Machine' from Free Code Camp web site via NetBeans IDE 8.2 and this code works well, but when I paste it on CodePen for some reason it doesn't work on CodePen full page view. Is there a way that I can make a page reload when I click on a button on CodePen full page view anyway?

In Debug mode view on CodePen it's working. Here's a link to my CodePen: https://codepen.io/NemStep/pen/pdmowz

Comment: It works just fine for me in full page mode. What browser are you using where full page mode doesn't work?

Comment: No where in the Pen that you linked do you have this code?

Comment: I have 50 quotes. After 50 clicks, the button name changes to 'Read again' and then the page refreshes. history.go (0); instead of location.reload (); solved my problem with CodePen.

Comment: It doesn’t work because CodePen replaces `location.reload()` by `location.removedByCodePen()`. Look into the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`). It says `TypeError: window.location.removedByCodePen is not a function`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an alternative to `location.reload`.

The parameter of go is the page index, in this case, 0 is the current page.
For instance, `go(-2)` would go 2 pages back in the history.

```js
$("#quoteButton").on("click", function() {
    history.go(0);
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thx! :P

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your pen:

```
function ref() {
  a = "reload";
  b = "location";
  window[b][a]();
}
```

then call it :D
or use self instead of window.