# Matrix intro, can't reload on CodePen. Going slowly on mobile devices(3D). JavaScript, Css

Tags: javascript

So. Like in my question, i create a Matrix intro, on my deskop(chrome) everything going smoothly. But, when i upload everything in to CodePen my animation stops on final step... Where is a issue?!

For sure there is a trouble with that part of code:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("spark");   
  var size = 0;
  var pos=50;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 1);
  function frame() {

      if(size>200){

       //if would you like to run animation ones and relocate user to your main website use  window.location.href=''; instead of location.reload();
       window.location.reload();
      }
      else{
        size+=2; 
      pos-=1;
      elem.style.top = pos+"%";
      elem.style.left = pos+"%";
      elem.style.width = size + '%'; 
      elem.style.height = size + '%'; 
      }
    }

},30000);
```

full code avaible on [codepen](https://codepen.io/codereaper/pen/RMeoaz)

I try to change size, use only location.reload() but nothing. on a spot when function should reload it stops...

2nd issue is that, my function executes so slow... on mobile devices(samsung J5). So there needs to be some problem also but with ones?!

history.go(0); not working eater.

Comment: full code is 150 length lines of code. Last step is spark, spark should restart all function, to let all function runs from beginning. so if i change interval instead of timeout i will need to change all 150 lines of code... there is maybe some other way?!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reload a web page on CodePen full page view by clicking a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47678907/how-to-reload-a-web-page-on-codepen-full-page-view-by-clicking-a-button)

Comment: history.go(0); wont work on  my case..